# How to make a class to use specific method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm trying to improve the way I write my code and this is one of the problems I recently encountered and it gave my quite a headeache.

I'm using NHibernate as ORM.

In my repositories I'm using static classes (ie. NHibernateHelperScheduler) to open sessions:

```
public class PlannedShiftsRepository : Repository<PlannedShiftsEvent>
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Get all records for provided machine_id
    ///</summary>
    public IList<PlannedShiftsEvent> SelectForMachine(string machine_id)
    {
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelperScheduler.OpenSession())
        {
            var myList = session.Query<PlannedShiftsEvent>().Where(c => c.machine_id == machine_id).ToList();

            return myList;
        }
    }
    }
```

The thing is I have more than one class NHibernateHelper with different configurations for different databases that are different in some configuration aspects.

```
public class NHibernateHelperScheduler
{

    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {

                var NHibernateConfig = new Configuration();
                NHibernateConfig.Configure(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                @"~\Models\NHibernate\hibernate.cfg.xml"), "Scheduler");
                NHibernateConfig.AddDirectory(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
                 @"~\Models\NHibernate\Mapping\Scheduler")));
                _sessionFactory = NHibernateConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

This caused some problems because repository can use different configuration files and work just fine and no one will notice an error. For different configuration the result from repo will always be 0. There won't be any errors.

Now my question is:

How can I make the repository to use ony specific class.

For example for obj type PlannedShiftsEvent use only methods from static class NHibernateHelperScheduler. Should some kind of contract through interfaces be used here ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly this sounds more like a design problem. I would recommend studying up on some GOF design patterns, such as the Bridge and Visitor design pattern. I see you are already using a good implementation of the Factory pattern, so maybe you should look into some others.

Comment: Yes this is a design question. I'll look in to the examples you provided.